# Перенос из sqlite в postresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Как можно перенести данные из формата sqlite в postgresql

На Python в Aiogram (Django не использую)

В других вопросах на сайте есть решения но сугубо для Django

Есть ли специальные библиотеки или чтото в это роде

Comment: Всё б вам библиотеки готовые... а ещё лучше екзешник с единственной кнопкой "Сделать песдато". Экспорт запросом в CSV из SQLite и последующий импорт другим запросом из файла в PostgreSQL. Ну а структуры - те всё одно вручную переносить.

Comment: Ну на счет библиотек да,хпхпх

Comment: Но спасибо за идею .csv

Answer (score 0):

Элементарно! sudo apt install pgloader - скачиваешь данную утиль. Далее тебе нужно подготовить две бд, учти что типы данных у этих субд отличаются немного. Если типы данных не буду совпадать, то ничего не перенесется. Потом берешь, прописываешь вот эту команду:
pgloader bot.db postgres://pguser:pgpasswrd@localhost/pg_db
Если все настроил правильно, то база перенесется за 1-5 сек.

Comment: а как сделать на винде?

Comment: А вот на Windows я не знаю как сделать, можно конечно заморочиться и самому скрипт написать, который будет извлекать данный из таблиц и типы данных. (sqlite) и потом записывать их в postgresql базу. Ну и если тип данных sqlite один, то в postgresql он другой (документация в помощь).